# Rank with Condition in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for a query that will calculate rank based on a condition, as following:

[image]

The "rank index" is the calculation I'm looking for - if the difference between previous time and current time is less than 6 hours, than the counter should remain the same. If more than 6 hours have past than promote the index by 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why does the last value go from 3 to 5 if the increment is by `1`?

Comment: (1) What is your Oracle version? Use `select * from v$version` if you don't know. (2) You said "six hours from the previous row". Is that correct, or do you need "six hours from the **first** row in the current rank"? Both are valid problems; the one you asked is less common, the one I described is more common (but also much more difficult). (3) What data type is `datetime`? It should be `date` or `timestamp` (or perhaps `timestamp with time zone`); your example just show some strings, presumably representing time-of-day, but what matters is the data type used for the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your explanation, the last value should be `4` not `5`.

Use `lag()` and a cumulative sum.  Assuming the `datetime` column is stored as a `date`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_datetime > datetime - interval '6' hour then 0 else 1 end) over
           (order by datetime) as rank_index
from (select t.*,
             lag(datetime) over (order by datetime) as prev_datetime
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note:  If you want this for each `key1`/`key2` combination, then you want to include `partition by key1, key2` in the window specifications.